# Does anybody use page-break-before style for PDF or XPS generation?

Tags: styles

I'm using a product called WebGrabber from ActivePDF, which programmatically generates PDF from web pages.
This tool has two rendering engines, a native one that does not honor CSS stylesheets so its not usable for my app and IE thats the one I use.
I need to generate some intentional pagebreaks and I've added some

```
<p style="page-break-before:always"></p>
```

where needed but neither with this tool nor printing out using Microsoft XPS Document Writer honors this style.

Does anybody have any experience doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

I needed to add a space here

```
<p style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</p>
```